# What does the underscore mean in entries of motorizations or car model series?

Tags: megane

Overall, I'm confused by the ways parts dealers label specific types of cars. One of the things I'm not clear on is what the underscore means with for example *BZ0_* (see [link 1](https://www.autokelly.cz/Catalog/osobni-automobil-nahradni-dily-renault/39849642;39850140;21) or [link 2](https://automedik.cz/autodily/renault)). My hypothesis is that instead of the underscore, there could be any other string, so it's some set from BZ0. I just haven't been able to verify this hypothesis on the internet.

Comment: I really don't think it means much of anything. Could be a French thing :P (J/K!) I see some of the entries have an underscore and others don't, so I don't think it's specific the their database. Probably something which Renault does for whatever reason. Your reasoning in this case is probably as reliable as any other.